# Grammatisch oder grammatikalisch?

Tags: difference, etymology, grammaticality, terminology

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen "grammatisch" und "grammatikalisch"? Ist am Ende eins von beiden falsch? Wenn ja, warum? Wie kommen diese beiden unterschiedlichen Wortformen zustande?

Answer (score 21):

Keiner der beiden Begriffe ist falsch. Sie bedeuten im Wesentlichen dasselbe, auch wenn sie nicht beliebig austauschbar sind.

- **grammatikalisch:** *ausschließlich* die Grammatik betreffend
- **grammatisch:** *zusätzlich* der Grammatik gemäß

Näheres [hier](http://faql.de/wortgebrauch.html#grammatikalisch).

Answer (score 11):

Der einzige Teil der Frage, der sich klar beantworten lässt, wurde, wenn mich nicht alles täuscht, von allen Vorrednern übersehen. Dieser lautet: 
**Wie kommen diese beiden unterschiedlichen Wortformen zustande**. Dies ist schnell geklärt. Bei "grammatisch" wurde direkt vom Griechischen ausgegangen, während bei "grammatikalisch" ein Umweg über das "grammaticalis" der Lateiner genommen wurde. **Weiter unten sehen wir, dass gerne dann auf die lateinische Form zugegriffen wurde, wenn die griechische bereits belegt war**.

Mir wurde vor Jahr und Tag von Deutschen Lehrern wieder und wieder die Auffassung eingedrillt, die sich auch hier findet:
[Bellesletres - grammatisch oder grammatikalisch](http://www.belleslettres.eu/blog/grammatikalisch-grammatisch.php/%22Bellesletres%22) . Demgemäß sollte man sagen "der Satz ist grammatikalisch falsch" und "das Wörterbuch ist grammatisch". Dass meine Lehrer keine Exoten waren, belegt auch dieser [Artikel des Zwiebelfisches](http://www.spiegel.de/kultur/zwiebelfisch/zwiebelfisch-abc-grammatisch-grammatikalisch-a-311690.html). Jahre lang glaubte ich, dass der [oben von splattne genannte](http://faql.de/wortgebrauch.html#grammatikalisch/%22oben%20genannte%20%22) und ausführlichere Artikel das exakte Gegenteil behaupte. Ich unterlag dem Fehlschluss, man sage *grammatikalisch falsch*, weil *grammatikalisch* sich auf die Richtigkeit beziehe. Jetzt bin ich aber der Überzeugung, dass man das so sagt, weil *grammatikalisch* die Richtigkeit **nicht** enthält und so der Ausdruck nicht doppelt gemoppelt ist.

Der wohl schnellste Weg zu dieser Erkenntnis führt über das Wort

> ***ungrammatisch***: nicht den Regeln der Grammatik entsprechend [gebildet]

Das legt zumindest stark nahe, dass *grammatisch* (unter anderem) die umgekehrte Bedeutung aufweise!

Nun zur Etymologie:

Unzweifelhaft ist der Ursprung das griechische ΓΡΑΜΜΑΤΙΚΗ (ΤΕΧΝΗ). Man betrachte ähnliche Wörter entlehnt aus den Namen griechischer Künste:

ΔΙΔΑΚΤΙΚΗ : didaktisch

ΔΙΑΛΕΚΤΙΚΗ: dialektisch

ΘΕΑΤΡΙΚΗ : theatrisch (selten; in Bezug auf die Schauspielkunst, siehe [hier](https://books.google.gr/books?id=l7ZKCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA94&lpg=PA94&dq=theatrisch&source=bl&ots=---PVlQfpp&sig=og5rGmgw5Vi2TXb11MvrHBefEQQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJipDVn-zcAhVHxaYKHd0pCOQQ6AEwDXoECAQQAQ#v=onepage&q=theatrisch&f=false) und [hier](https://books.google.gr/books?id=61znCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA255&lpg=PA255&dq=theatrisch&source=bl&ots=Eg-bpmSpXV&sig=3bFmm5J1t1Cw5cJI6HiK1mDjdWg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiJipDVn-zcAhVHxaYKHd0pCOQQ6AEwEnoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=theatrisch&f=false). *Theatralisch* in deutlich anderer Bedeutung!)

ΡΗΤΟΡΙΚΗ: rhetorisch

ΕΡΜΗΝΕΥΤΙΚΗ: hermeneutisch

ΠΟΙΗΤΙΚΗ: poetisch

ΦΥΣΙΚΗ (ΦΙΛΟΣΟΦΙΑ): **physikalisch** (*physisch* bedeutet etwas anderes).

Man könnte diese Liste sehr, sehr lang machen und würde feststellen dass die Begriffe auf "-alisch" - bei denen ein zusätzlicher Umweg über das Lateinische gemacht wurde - seltener sind. Darüber hinaus fällt **physikalisch** bereits aus der Reihe. Ich bin mir recht gewiss, dass schon die Alten es der Philosophie und nicht der Kunst zuordneten. Es scheint als würde die Form auf -alisch vor allem gewählt, wenn die direkte Ableitung aus dem Griechischen bereits mit einer anderen Bedeutung belegt ist!

Dies sind meiner Ansicht nach gute Argumente dafür, dass "grammatisch" eine konsequentere Übertragung aus dem Altgriechischen darstellt.

Edit:

Ich finde es jedoch (nachdem ich das Beispiel „theatrisch“ gefunden, und den Prozess besser begriffen zu haben glaube) sehr schwierig zu entscheiden, ob eine Unterscheidung zwischen *grammatisch* (dem Wesen nach Grammatik) und *grammatikalisch* (auf die Grammatik bezogen) nützlich ist. Beantwortet man, diese Frage mit „Nein“, so ist ein Verzicht auf *grammatikalisch* konsequent.

Comment: Ich finde den Gedanken einer Unterscheidung von *theatrisch* und *theatralisch* sehr anregend. Selbst wenn es *theatrisch* noch nicht gab, ab jetzt sollte es verwendet werden. Ohne Theatralik natürlich, einfach statt "theaterbezüglich".

Answer (score 2):

Für mich klingt es aufgrund der Beispiele so, als sei der Unterschied dieser:
**grammatikalisch** bezieht sich auf das eine Aktion (*sprechen, schreiben*, also **Verben**, oder eben auf das **Adjektiv** *falsch*), also ist es ein **Adverb**.
**grammatisch** ist ein **Adjektiv**.

Da sich Adverbien und Adjektive im Deutschen in ihrer Form nicht unterscheiden, bemerken wir den Unterschied nicht. Schauen wir aber auf die Verwendung der Wörter im Kontext, wird relativ schnell klar, dass etwas, was *grammatisch falsch ist*, *grammatikalsich falsch produziert wurde*.

Answer (score 0):

In der Umgangssprache ist "grammatikalisch" fast immer besser als "grammatisch". Wir haben das in der Schule so gelernt (70er Jahre), und wenn wir gesagt hätten "Das ist grammatisch falsch", hätte man uns mit "grammatikalisch" verbessert.

Also egal, was "grammatisch" wirklich bedeutet, es klingt in der Umgangssprache einfach falsch.

Comment: Klänge es falsch würde es kaum so gerne benutzt, oder? Oder benützt?

Comment: Die Sprache ändert sich. Früher war "grammatisch" einfach falsch. Daher hab ich auch "70er Jahre" geschrieben.

Comment: Laut Splattnes Link ist "grammatisch" aber wesentlich älter als 1970, war also damals bereits richtig, und der Lehrer hätte es nicht korrigieren müssen, wenn es nicht gesagt worden wäre. Es muss wohl einen Aufsatz in einer Zeitung gegeben haben - mir wurde in den 70ern auch "grammatikalisch" beigebracht.

Comment: Ich habe das Wort "grammatisch" noch nie gehört und ich war in den 90ern in der Schule. Deshalb würde ich im Alltag auch eher zu "grammatikalisch" greifen.

Comment: Sagt man statt „grammatisch falsch“ nicht besser „nicht grammatisch“ oder „ungrammatisch“? Genauso würde man doch sagen: „Dieser Satz ist sehr wohl grammatisch.“ und nicht: „Dieser Satz ist sehr wohl grammatisch richtig.“

Comment: Hier (Berliner Umland) ist grammatikalisch bspw. recht unüblich. Man hört beides, aber in der Umgangssprache ist (und war anscheinend) `grammatisch` viel öfter verwendet.

Comment: "grammatisch" ist deutlich häufiger in Gebrauch, als "grammatikalisch" (siehe [hier](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=grammatisch%2Cgrammatikalisch&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=31&smoothing=2&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgrammatisch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cgrammatikalisch%3B%2Cc0) ). Für mich klingt "grammatikalisch" falsch; war aber auch in den Neunzigern in der Schule.